# What is the fastest way to reinstall StarCraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2

For some reason, I have to uninstall StarCraft 2 and want to reinstall again. So, after uninstalled, if I try to install again will the install launcher still have to download again 13GB from Battle.net server?

Or is there any important files to save and then I can reinstall without downloading so much GB?

Comment: I suppose that depends on why you're reinstalling the game. If you need a clean installation then you shouldn't keep any of the old files...

Comment: Copy all the files somewhere else. When you need to reinstall the game, just copy them back over to the default folder where Battle.net installs games, it will detect the installed files next time you run Bnet and possibly download updates only and not all the game files..

Comment: @DrFish you mean, should I take backup all files under this folder: C:\Program Files\StarCraft II  ??

Comment: @JohnG exactly.

Comment: Why are you reinstalling? If it's due to some type of configuration problem, backing up all the files that way might also preserve the problem, thus making your reinstall not help. Consider changing "for some reason" in your question to the actual reason in order to get better answers. @DrFish: why not make an answer out of your comment?

Comment: @DanHenderson done :)

Comment: @DanHenderson I too would like to know what "some reason" means...

Answer (score 2):

Backup your complete Starcraft II folder to someplace else. When you need to reinstall the game, just copy them back over to the default folder where Battle.net installs games.

It will then detect the installed files next time you run Battle.Net and possibly download updates only and not all the game files.